# not enough space to show ad wants 480 75

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I tried a lot of things to do, but nothing helps. My problem is that my `admob ad` is not displaying and `LogCat` is writing this:

```
03-19 12:30:56.140: E/Ads(790): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <432, 690>
03-19 12:30:56.140: E/Ads(790): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <432, 357>
```

May be the problem is with emulator, not code? Will be very greatful for any help
My `manifest.xml`:

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.gosha.whymod.MainActiviti"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`MainActivity.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActiviti" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/knopka"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Get answer now" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texte"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Why modern art is so strange?"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/knopka"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1837185169360297/2930943167"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/knopka"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1837185169360297/2930943167"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" />
```

with

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/knopka"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1837185169360297/2930943167"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the paddingLeft and paddingRight from your RelativeLayout. That is what is causing the reduced display area.

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are testing on an **HDPI** device and **AdView** needs 480x75 px to display an advert. of **BANNER** size

In your XML layout file, the parent **RelativeLayout** (Seems like auto created) **padding values to left and right**. Which will produce an activity less width than the actual screen resolution. So the inlaying child **AdView** will only get lesser screen size than 480p

Try to put a parent **FrameLayout** with **RelativeLayout** and **AdView** as childs, so the **AdView** will appear as an overlay on **RelativeLayout**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActiviti" >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <Button android:id="@+id/knopka"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Get answer now" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/texte"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Why modern art is so strange?"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/knopka"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1837185169360297/2930943167"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" />
```